# Why does ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the text off inside the "Other areas of Wikipedia" section on the Wikipedia front page. However, I run into the error `ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'`. What's wrong with my code and how do I get it to work?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml' )
otherAreasContainer = soup.find_all('div', class_='mp-bordered')
otherAreasContainerTexts = otherAreasContainer.find_all('li')
for otherAreasContainerText in otherAreasContainerTexts:
    print(otherAreasContainerText.text)
```

Comment: The full stack trace would help. We can't see which line number is causing the error.

Comment: Please post the full traceback so that we can see the extact error text and line causing the problem.

Comment: Maybe `find_all` returns a `list` or a iterator, and you're trying to do a `find_all` on a list object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `otherAreasContainer` is of type `ResultSet`, and `ResultSet` doesn't have `.find_all()` method.

To select all `<li>` from under the `"Other areas of Wikipedia"`, you can use CSS selector `h2:contains("Other areas of Wikipedia") + div li`.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'lxml')

for li in soup.select('h2:contains("Other areas of Wikipedia") + div li'):
    print(li.text)
```

Prints:

```
Community portal – Bulletin board, projects, resources and activities covering a wide range of Wikipedia areas.
Help desk – Ask questions about using Wikipedia.
Local embassy – For Wikipedia-related communication in languages other than English.
Reference desk – Serving as virtual librarians, Wikipedia volunteers tackle your questions on a wide range of subjects.
Site news – Announcements, updates, articles and press releases on Wikipedia and the Wikimedia Foundation.
Village pump – For discussions about Wikipedia itself, including areas for technical issues and policies.
```

---

More about [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Running your code I got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h.py", line 7, in <module>
    otherAreasContainerTexts = otherAreasContainer.find_all('li')
  File "/home/td/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1620, in __getattr__
    "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

This should be part of your question - make it easy for us to spot your problem!

`find_all` returns a `ResultSet` which essentially a list of elements found. You need to enumerate each of the elements to continue

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml' )
otherAreasContainer = soup.find_all('div', class_='mp-bordered')
for other in otherAreasContainer:
    otherAreasContainerTexts = other.find_all('li')
    for otherAreasContainerText in otherAreasContainerTexts:
        print(otherAreasContainerText.text)
```

Comment: Thanks but I got elements from other sections of the homepage, such as "Arts
Biography
Geography
History
Mathematics
Science
Society
Technology
All portals"
​

Answer (score 0):

Result of `find_all` is a list, and list has not `find` or `find_all` attribute, you must iterate  `otherAreasContainer` and then call `find_all` method on it, like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
otherAreasContainer = soup.find_all('div', class_='mp-bordered')

for other in otherAreasContainer:
    otherAreasContainerTexts = other.find_all('li')

    for otherAreasContainerText in otherAreasContainerTexts:
        print(otherAreasContainerText.text)
```

Comment: What do you mean by list has not attribute "find"? Thanks.

Comment: The list is one of the data type in python like array in other languages, the list support itself methods like append not `find` or `find_all`, these methods is just for bs4 objects.